# Redux state is always returning me the intial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I created a state named 'VendorItemSelect' in the redux store. It is intialized with empty array. I have a component named vendorTable and I'm connecting to the store using connect function.

On Checking a checkbox I'm dispacthing an action to store to update my state. This pushes a new object (row) into my array and redux state is updated with new state.

On Checking of another checkbox, it should return the state from store which contains new object added via dispacthing action and it should push a new object. Now, it should contain an array of two objects.

But redux state is always returning me empty array and state is updated with new row all the time. I'm pasting some code and screenshots here:

**Code where I'm dispatching action:**

```
  let items = updateItems(selectedItem, row.original);
          dispatch(setVendorListItem(items)); /
```

**Getting props from redux store:**

```
export const VendorsItemTable = ({ onSubmit , defaultRfqSelected, selectedItem, ReceivedRFQs }) => {
```

**MapStateToProps:**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    defaultRfqSelected: state.rfq.selectedRow,
    ReceivedRFQs: state.rfq.RFQList,
    selectedItem: state.rfq.vendorItemSelect,
  };
};
```

**My reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
    selectedRow: 0,
    RFQList: [],
    selectRFQROW: {},
    quoteSent: '',
    vendorItemSelect: [],
    vendorSelect:[],
};


export const RFQReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'RowSelection' :   return {
            ...state,
            selectedRow: action.payload,
        };
        case 'RFQList' : return {
            ...state,
            RFQList: action.payload,
        }
        case 'RFQQuote' : return {
            ...state,
            quoteSent: action.payload,
        }
        case 'RFQVendor': return {
            ...state,
            vendorSelect: action.payload,
        }
        case 'RFQVendorItem': return{
            ...state,
            vendorItemSelect : action.payload,
        }
        default:
            return state
       
    }
}
```

**RFQActions:**

export function UpdateRowSelection  (data)  {
return {
type: 'RowSelection',
payload: data
}
}

export function SetRFQRowList ( data) {
return {
type: 'RFQList',
payload: data
}
}

export function setVendorListItem (data) {
return{
type: 'RFQVendorItem',
payload: data
}
}

export function setVendorName (data) {
return{
type: 'RFQVendor',
payload: data
}
}

[[image: Redux state after one dispatchState value in console after second click...its still empty array]

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include complete code examples of the React components and redux code so we're not left guessing how the pieces fit together? See [mcve]. I don't see ***any*** `RFQReducer` reducer cases that update the `vendorItemSelect` array in state. In fact... none of the reducer cases update the nested properties, they just replace them with whatever you are dispatching in the action payloads.

Comment: Hi Drew, I updated the post with rfq actions, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

The action `setVendorListItem` should update the `vendorItemSelect` array as well, but instead it only updates the `selectedItem` variable.

To correct this, alter the case of the `RFQVendorItem` in your reducer to:

```
case 'RFQVendorItem': return {
    ...state,
    vendorItemSelect: [...state.vendorItemSelect, action.payload],
};
```

By doing this, a new row will be added to the `vendorItemSelect` array.

Additionally, you must confirm that the component that is checking the checkbox is the one from which the `setVendorListItem` action is being dispatched.

So then:

1. Modify your reducer's `RFQVendorItem` case to match the code above.
2. Check to see that the component that is checking the checkbox is the one that is dispatching the `setVendorListItem` action.